# Update price on product page with JS component and add to cart

Tags: magento2, product, magento-2.1, cart, price

I update the product price (.price-box) on the product page via some custom JS component. When putting the product into cart it still has the old value from before the update.

How can I put the product into cart with the new price without actually saving the product with the new price but keeping it in cart and checkout?

Comment: Dava,
Did you write a function?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Magento 1.x if not let me know and I'll provide M2 version

You need to do this by hooking into the add to cart action using the observer and do something similar to this

```
private function replaxePrice($product_id,$newPrice){

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); 

foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
if($item->getProduct()->getId() != $product_id) continue; 

if ($newPrice > 0) { 
$item->setCustomPrice($newPrice);

$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($newPrice);
 $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); 
} 
}
 $quote->save(); 
}
```

Sorry about poor formatting. Only certain thing I can do on mobile

Why reinvent the wheel, I has someone ask me this recently and I sent them this reference

Updated for M2

https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/

Hope this resolved your issues

Comment: This looks like some M1 snippet, I am on M2 ;-) Furthermore how should I get the price from my Frontend JS component? Doesn't sound like a viable solution to be honest

Comment: Ahh.. sorry - I disnt read your updated version.. yes M2

Comment: Same principle really you just need to hook into the add to cart event and update price similar to M1

Comment: But the new price is calculated only in JS. How shall I pass it to the event?

Comment: Iv updated my post that should point u in right direction

Comment: Not really. The new price cannot be accesses in the observer, as it is neither saved on the quote item nor on the product object itself. The new price is a JS calculated price which is only created with JS, So I cannot access it in PHP. I'll probably create a hidden input field. I thought there is a better solution.

Comment: Sorry phone is about to die I will write function for you tomorrow and post the result first thing